# SSAS and use of MDX queries

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, ssas-2008

Use and Purpose of MDX queries.
I have started creating cubes and SSAS project but haven't used whole lot of MDX queries.
Is MDX queries used for querying cubes???
Have tried but not successful
Let me know.

Comment: Please ignore "Have tried but not successful Let me know." -- I think stackoverflow did force me to use above statement.. Bottom line Question: All i wanted to know is Purpose of MDX queries and where/when to use it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use MDX to query cubes like you use SQL SELECT statements to query relational databases.

However, there are a lot of reporting tools that generate the MDX queries so that you do not have to write them manually.

Comment: Thanks for response Frank. Can you give me some reporting tools that generate the MDX queries automatic.

Comment: Apart from Excel (Pivot tables as well as Power View) and Reporting Services, which are from Microsoft, there are many from third party providers, you can find some listed here: http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/category/client-tools/ and here: http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-client-tools-frontend.